# Setting fullscreen exclusive mode for JavaFX desktop application

Tags: javafx, fullscreen

Does everybody know how to apply fullscreen exclusive mode for JavaFX desktop application? Because when application is running and some message appears on the screen (for example, network connection aborted), my application looses fullscreen mode :(

Answer (score -2):

As a last resort i think you can kill the Explorer (on Windows) on app startup and restart it when you quit. Although I do think this is in

Comment: "Although I do think this is in" - is in what?

Comment: This is **totally inappropriate**. No application is supposed to kill explorer.exe!